# Other ways to call your friend instead of «moço» in Portugal and Brazil

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças-transatlânticas, dialetos-insulares

> A: Olá, moço! Como estás?
>
> B: Bem e tu?
>
> A: Eu vou ótimo, obrigado!

Is *moço* a common expression to call your friend in both countries?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá "moço": Olá, cara; Olá, mano; E aí, rapaz.

Depende muito do contexto, região e costume. Enquanto que em Portugal se diz *gajo* para *moço*, no Brasil não costumamos nem dizer "olá, moço", principalmente nós homens. Olá tem uma leve significação cultural de ser usado por mulheres.

Já no contexto de atendimento, ou servência semi-informal, usa-se.

Eis o exemplo:

> "Olá, moço, em que posso ajudá-lo?"
>
> "Olá moço, você gostaria de conhecer nossa nova promoção?"

(Digo, desde já, que não existe "presente-infinitivo-gerúndio" em Português. É uma prática incorreta na nossa língua, que foi pega erroneamente por pessoas de educação formal pobre, ainda que algumas tenham mérito do diploma de ensino superior.)

Além disso, nas conversas informais, e até mesmo nas formais, raramente se usam as flexões verbais que dizem respeito à segunda pessoa do singular e plural (tu e vós).
Usamos, no Brasil, eu, ele, nós e eles. (E vocês, que vem do vós, do «vossa mercê».)

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar que 'Olá' era algo a ser usado por mulheres, 'oi' e 'olá' dá no mesmo. A expressão 'olá, moço' é comum ser usada por mulheres, pois soa informal de uso feminino. Moço também é usado para se falar de alguém, geralmente de um homem jovem desconhecido, "Aquele moço comprou algo aqui", .

Answer (score 8):

In Brazil and as an addressing, "moço" is generally used to address an unknown young man or teenager.

> — Moço, poderia me dizer as horas?

Informally, it can also be used between people that know each other or friends, like:

> — Você vai lá?
>   — Cê acha, moço, não sou louco!

For the informal usage, it can be replaced with the slangs "cara", "véi" (short for "velho"), "mano", "meu", "maluco", and so on.

> — E aí, cara!
>   — E aí, véi, beleza?
>   — Beleza, mano.
>   — Meu, você não vai lá?

"Maluco" is used in less contexts and is used informally just like the informal "moço".

> — Fui fazer uma prova ontem...  Maluco, que prova difícil era aquela!

For the formal usage, "rapaz" can also be used. A "rapaz" is a young adult male. Although the situations when it can be used are not the same. For example, if you say *"Rapaz, poderia me dizer as horas?"*, it may sound **a bit** over-formal or as if you are serious with this person. It can also be used in a serious/angry tone to mean the same as the informal "moço", as in:

> — Está achando o que, rapaz? Levante daí e faça alguma coisa!

Or in normal tone, used the same way as "maluco".

Just a note: all of these words are just a form of expression when used informally, i.e. if someone says to you "moço" and you are 50+ years old, or "véi" and you are teenager, or "maluco", it doesn't mean they are saying you are such.

---

About your example dialogue, at least in Brazil and in non-formal situations, men don't usually say "olá" or "oi" to each other. "Olá" is a little more formal than "oi", and when "oi" is used in these situations, it's commonly to or from females. Instead, we usually say "e aí". Of course, in other situations it's fine to use it.

Comment: "Véi" vem de "velho" não é?

Comment: @JorgeB Sim, apesar de "velho" não ser muito comum quanto "véi".

Comment: Essas gírias da listinha são mais comuns em um ou outro canto separadamente. Vai ouvir um "véio" em Minas Gerais ou um "Meu" em São Paulo capital, mas não vai ser natural em qualquer canto. E são gírias usadas por jovens ou adolescentes.

Comment: @AndréLyra Sim, claro, mas são alternativas.

Answer (score 5):

In Portugal  you can simply say "Olá, como estás/vais?"
We really don't use "moço" to address people in Portugal.

If it's your friend and you are informal, you can use "meu" or "pá", these are somewhat equivalent to "dude". So be aware that in a situation where you can call a dude "dude", you can call him "pá". :)

Comment: In informal youth (and perhaps street?) contexts the word moço **is** used in Portugal. `Hei moço, 'tás porreiro? Choca aí, mano.`

Comment: I'm getting old...

Comment: It could also be that it's used where I live, but not where you live. :)

Comment: Não esqueçamos _sócio_ :p

Comment: And the almighty 'meu'

Comment: In Portuguese slang, you may also say *puto*, *boy*, *meu*, *sócio* or *jovem* for good friends.

Answer (score 3):

*Olá, moço! Como estas?* dá a ideia que é um senhor mais velho a falar com um jovem. Talvez "rapaz" em Portugal seja o que tu queres, *Então rapaz, está tudo bem?*.

Em Portugal usam-se muitas coisas diferentes, como disse o [@JorgeCanelhas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/3149/153), "meu" e "pá" *like dude*, num tom muito mais informal.

No norte de Portugal usa-se muito o "mano" *like bro*. Cada frase acaba ou começa por "mano" certamente, por exemplo:

> - Mano, estava a tomar leite e não encontrei o chocapic, mano.
> - Yah, mano, essa cena é boa, mano.

<sup>*PS: eu ouvi mesmo uma conversa assim*</sup>

Comment: Em Portugal usa-se "yah"? Essa é nova pra mim. :)

Comment: @BrunoLopes não sei se é assim que se escreve, mas é *yah man* ou *yah mano tás a ber a cena?* com aquele sotaque do Porto/Braga.

Comment: @JorgeB. Desde quando é que *pá* leva ***h?*** Vê [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/p%C3%A1) e [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/p%C3%A1); em ambos é preciso descer um bocado até encontrar a aceção relevante.

Comment: @Jacinto é hábito de escrever...

Comment: Jorge, acho que aquele «like bro» não fica bem, em inglês ali no meio do português.

Comment: @ANeves eu acho ;)